# valueChanges does not emit value on input typing after apply switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I am wondering what is wrong with my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rc4fq8. I use widgetNameForm$ to pass to child component. Whereas switchMap should switch to valueChanges stream and emit value on input typing but such approach surprisingly does not work. Previously I used other code described bellow but it has nested subscription and I would like to stick with more reactive approach like described on stackblitz

```
 this.widgetName$.subscribe(val => {
  this.widgetNameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [val, {validators: Validators.required}]
  });

  this.widgetNameForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe(val => console.log('it emits value on typing', val));
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 different subscriptions:

- one in constructor
- one in template via `async` pipe

Your problem is that each subscription will receive a separate instance of a `FormGroup`.  This means the instance you subscribe to in your controller is not what is being passed to the child component and bound to the form, therefore no `valueChanges` are ever emitted.

You can resolve this by sharing a single subscription by using the [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) operator:

```
this.widgetNameForm$ = this.widgetName$.pipe(
  map(val => this.formBuilder.group({ name: [val, {validators: Validators.required}] })),
  shareReplay() // <---
);
```

Check out [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66973313?file=src/app/app.component.ts).  Notice the "instance id" is shown in the input field.  If you comment out the `shareReplay()` line you can see that you end up with 2 instances; with it you get only one.